# Nicely formatted text file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I’m writing to a text file and it looks like this...

> ```
> 19/05/2010 15:33:34   Verbose Main    in main method
> 19/05/2010 15:33:34   Information DoesSomethingInteresting()  the answer to faster than light travel is
> ```

But what i’d like it to look like is...

> ```
> 19/05/2010 15:33:34   Verbose     Main                        in main method
> 19/05/2010 15:33:34   Information DoesSomethingInteresting()  the answer to faster than light travel is
> ```

You know, so it's all nicely formatted and tabbed aligned. Is there an easy way to do this, some function in the runtime that will deal with all the tedious padding?

Here is my code that does the writing

```
LogFile.Write(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", log.Time, log.Level, log.Method, log.Message));
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To align a string to the left use formatting pattern with comma (,) followed by a negative number of characters:

```
LogFile.Write(string.Format("{0,-10} {1,-11} {2,-30} {3}", ...));
```

For right alignment use a positive number.