# Writing to a text file Python

Tags: python, arrays, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing nicely formatted text in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821083/writing-nicely-formatted-text-in-python)

I have this code for writting a header into the created txt file:

```
if not os.path.exists('list.txt'):
    f= file('list.txt', 'w')
    f.write ("\t".join("".join (str(row)) for row in header_names.keys()))+"\n")
    f.write ("\n")
```

And this is the code I use to append new rows to the text file:

```
f = open("list.txt","a")

f.write ("\t".join("".join (str(row)) for row in header_names.values()))+"\n")
f.write ("\n")
f.close()
```

The output that get's written in the text file isn't as I want it do be:

```
Name    some number some number2    % percentage    average
Test    2   2   100.0   0.4
TestTestTest    3   4   75.0    0.49
tes 2   3   66.67   0.33
```

I would like something like this:

```
Name           some number  some number2    % percentage    average
Test           2            2               100.0           0.4
Test           2            2               100.0           0.4
TestTestTest   3            4               75.0            0.49
tes            2            3               66.67           0.33
```

Is there any simple way to achieve this. It it's not mandatory it's written into the txt like that, but the output from reading should....

Comment: use format strings "%-6s" will give you a text width of 6 with the text right aligned ... or maybe left aligned ...

Comment: use the tab character? (\t)

Answer (score 3):

Format each column to a certain width, for instance:

```
>>> header = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> print [format(el, '<30') for el in header]
['one                           ', 'two                           ', 'three                         ']
>>> print ''.join(format(el, '<30') for el in header)
one                           two                           three
```

Comment: @user1509923 Look at the "Aligning the text and specifying a width:" section of [this doc page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) to see different formatting examples.

Comment: Thank you, i'm learing new things every day :D